# Java unending while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Okay so I am a total noob when it comes to Java so apologies if this is a stupid question. 
I have a while loop set up like so:

```
do {
  //quiz questions, lose a life when you get one wrong
} while (livesRemain > 0)
```

However, when you lose all of your lives the loop does not end and continues through the loop even when all lives are lost. Would I use something else other than while or do while that will end when a certain condition is reached?

The questions are like this:

```
 System.out.print(question1) 
    if (guess == 1) {
    System.out.print("Correct")
    score++;
    } else {
    livesRemain--;
}
```

When you reach the end of the quiz, it prints your score which ends up going into the negatives if you go below 0.

Comment: Well ... You forgot the most important part in the body of your loop: The statement that changes the variable `livesRemain`. Maybe it isn't there?

Comment: If you want us to spot a bug in your code, post the code.

Comment: This snippet looks correct. Can you share the actual code of losing a life? Seems as though something went wrong there.

Comment: the `while`-loop looks fine. Have you made sure, that `livesRemain` is actually decremented? Maybe there exist two variables with the same name. Hard to tell though without code

Comment: I am 100% sure there is nothing wrong with your loop. Neither do you need to use other types of loop. The only reason in the universe why the loop is not ending is because `livesRemain` is **still** more than 0.

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of this problem, post the codes in the body of the loop.

Comment: You've been asked to post the code many times already, and all you have posted is a short, uncompilable snippet, that thus can't be the actual code you're running. Post the real code. The one that actuallly runs and has the bug.

Comment: My crystal ball says to me, "Self, this guy is asking all the questions, one after another, all in the same loop pass.  He should make sure only one question is asked per loop".  Is my crystal ball right?

Answer (score 5):

You should try something like:

```
do {
      if(wrong) 
        livesRemain--;
} while (livesRemain > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the loop is not ending:

[image]

- When you are inside the do-while loop, it will remain in the loop as long as the condition meets (i.e. `liveRemaining > 0`)
- The variable `livesRemaining` is decremented outside the loop.
- Hence, `livesRemaining` is always > 0 since you are not updating it anywhere in the loop.
- Resulting loop not to end.

---

> Would I use something else other than while or do while that will end when a certain condition is reached?

The issue is not with choosing a suitable loop. The problem is caused by terminating condition not updated. To solve this problem, bring your codes into the loop so that the terminating condition can be met.

```
do{
    //Ask question..
    if(guess == 1)
        System.out.println("Correct");
    else
        livesRemain--;     //Update livesRemain
}while(livesRemain > 0);   //Keeping asking questions till lives == 0
```